# Computer totally hangs, what logs should I check

Tags: 14.04

I use ubuntu 14. About three days ago computer started hanging when I work - I even can't move mouse, so I press power button to restart the computer. It happens about 1-7 times an hour. For example I work in open office and it hangs. Or I work with console - it hangs. I can't understand what it can be and what logs I should check. What should I do?

Comment: `/var/log/kern.log`, the logs in `/var/log/X/` and `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: Are you sure that the partition is not full?